# JsonServiceClient C# In Excel COM Add-In

Tags: json, servicestack

We develop an Excel COM Add-In using add-in express. We have been using this add-in past 6 months and we don't have any issue. Past few weeks we start facing an issue in the add-in and after debugging I found that we have an issue with the communication channel between add-in and service stack web service. I am not sure quite what has been changed but we are getting error.

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

I tried to use the same line of codes in the LINQPad, and it works fine. But in the add-in, it does not work and generates the above error.

```
using (var client = new JsonServiceClient(_config.SchemaServiceUrl))
{
    client.UserName = login;
    client.Password = password;

    response = client.Get<AuthenticateResponse>("/auth");
}
```

Any suggestions or comments on this?

Regards,
Jamil

Comment: I think I found it. I just notice that it's an issue with the SSL certificate configured with my Web Service. So the code is fine with "HTTP"  url.